# Where condition with a specific hour and minute from a Timestamp SQL

Tags: sql

I have to search for a particular hour and minute within a column of a table.

For example:

```
activitydate (timestamp without time zone)
---------------------
"2021-02-11 00:00:00"
"2021-02-01 00:00:00"
"2021-02-03 03:00:00"
"2021-02-04 00:00:00"
"2021-02-05 05:00:00"
"2021-02-05 00:00:00"
"2021-02-08 07:00:00"
```

I wanted to run a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE activitydate_hour = '03: 00 '
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: please tag with database platform

Comment: Tag your question with the database you a e using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, you would use:

```
where extract(hour from activitydate) = 3
```

However, not all databases support `extract()`, so your database might have bespoke syntax.